# Cannot clone a package from github (publickey)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to do eye-to-hand using the following package https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/hand_eye_calibration/hand_eye_calibration_tutorial.html , however when I am cloning the git repository I am getting this error

```
git clone git@github.com:ros-planning/moveit_calibration.git
Cloning into 'moveit_calibration'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407766/cannot-clone-a-package-from-github-(publickey)/) by [akumar3.1428](https://answers.ros.org/users/110426/akumar3.1428/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2022-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you ! I followed the following commands to add public ssh key to my github

```
cd ~/.ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your email id "
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add
```

Open VS Code and copy ssh

```
cd ~/.ssh
code .

login into github 
go to setting 
go to ssh and gp keys
add new key 
paste it
```

---

Originally posted by [akumar3.1428](https://answers.ros.org/users/110426/akumar3.1428/) with karma: 61 on 2022-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You either need to [set up an ssh key with Github](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account), or clone it with https like this (which just requires a username and password):

```
git clone https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_calibration.git
```

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2022-10-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1